# Why does selecting one item in my React-Native FlatList trigger a re-render of all items?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm new to React-Native and trying to investigate why all items in my FlatList are re-rendering when I select one of them.

This is the code of the list:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import Task from './Task';
import useTasks from '../hooks/useTasks';
import TaskListHeader from './TaskListHeader';

export default function Tasks({ header: Header }) {
    const [title, image, list] = useTasks()
    const [doneTasksCount, setDoneTasksCount] = useState(0)

    const updateCounter = (isDone) => {
        isDone ? setDoneTasksCount(doneTasksCount + 1) : setDoneTasksCount(doneTasksCount - 1)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const count = list.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.isDone ? ++acc : acc, 0)
        setDoneTasksCount(count)
    }, [list])

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return <Task {...item} updateCounter={updateCounter} />;
    };

    const header = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <Header />
                <TaskListHeader
                    title={title}
                    imageURL={image}
                    allTasksCount={list.length}
                    doneTasksCount={doneTasksCount}
                />
            </>
        )
    }

    return <>
        <FlatList
            data={list}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={({ task }) => task}
            ListHeaderComponent={header}
            style={styles.list}
        />
    </>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    list: {
        backgroundColor: '#EBFFEE'
    }
})
```

And the code of the list item is this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";

export default function Task({task, icon, isDone, updateCounter}) {
    const [isMarked, setIsMarked] = useState(isDone)

    const handlePress = () => {
        setIsMarked(!isMarked)
        updateCounter(!isMarked)
    };

    return <View style={[styles.content, isMarked ? styles.markedContent : styles.unmarkedContent]}>
        {console.log(`render ${task}`)}
        <View style={styles.info}>
            <Image source={icon} style={styles.icon} />
            <Text style={[styles.title, isMarked ? styles.markedTitle : null]}>{task}</Text>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.actionButton, isMarked ? styles.markedButton : styles.unmarkedButton]}
            onPress={handlePress}
        >
            <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>{isMarked ? "Feito" : "Fazer"}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    content: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginBottom: 14,
        borderRadius: 16,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        maxHeight: 100,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        marginHorizontal: 16
    },
    icon: {
        width: 22,
        height: 22
    },
    info: {
        paddingLeft: 14,
        paddingVertical: 32,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    title: {
        marginLeft: 14,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    actionButton: {
        height: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonTitle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginHorizontal: 14
    },
    markedButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#00EA17'
    },
    unmarkedButton: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF5D5D'
    },
    markedTitle: {
        textDecorationLine: 'line-through'
    },
    markedContent: {
        backgroundColor: '#E1EFF2'
    },
    unmarkedContent: {
        backgroundColor: '#BDBCFF'
    }
})
```

The list has a header where I display the number of selected items.

I tried to use React.memo at the Task component but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you share the code from `useTasks`? And will be good share code in expo snack.